# Getting Android Auto on car head unit running Android 4.4.2

Tags: installation, android-auto, automotive-head-unit

I got a 2018 car recently (Suzuki SX4) and it's got Android 4.4.2 with no Android Auto installed.

When plugging into the right USB port in the car (and enabling debug USB mode on my phone, OnePlus) it just tries to install some mob interconnection service and what appears to be its own drivetime tool.

Also, no luck using Bluetooth.

Would love to know if there's any way to enable Android Auto in this context.

Thank you